# How to prevent duplicate Integer new value in database?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, duplicates

In my Spring Boot Java application, in the db, there are entries added regularly to an entity (XEntity) with some Integer field that is unique ("some_fieldId").
There are already a lot of entries added (autoincremented from 1 to about 6000000).

Now, in a new feature, some other third party will add entries too but I need to be sure that "some_fieldId" doesn't already exist. They naturally wanted to start with the first id=1.

What strategy may I suggest to them for generating that Integer field ("some_fieldId") in order to preserve unicity?

Something that I have in my mind is to generate only negative ids, but they don't agree too much with that.

Comment: Why doesn't the other party let the id be autoincremented by the db?

Comment: they generated it before reaching my db

Comment: Do they need to? One possibility might be to generate the values in the db and return the generated ids. Otherwise you'll have a hard time synchronizing the values properly without some hacks.

Comment: When multiple parties outside the control of the database try to create unique identifiers, a UUID is a beter/safer solution. Next to impossible to create a conflicting id.

Answer (score 1):

You should pair-up XEntity with name of unique thirdparty column as a pair-unique constraint such that Id 1->+inf is unique for all third parties involved. If Id is primary key then use composite key as primary key.